# How to give a command multiple names?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hellothere(ctx):
   await Bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author))
```

I want to make a copy of this command that is shorter.

I tried:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
   hellothere(ctx)
```

But I received an error stating that `Command` is not callable.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Command.invoke` coroutine.  Something like

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await hellothere.invoke(ctx)
```

Answer (score 39):

`@client.command(pass_context = True , aliases=['purge', 'clean', 'delete'])`

Just change the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another more "hacky" way (by making two commands using the same function but with different names, this uses the `.callback` attribute of `Command`):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hellothere(ctx):
    await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author))

bot.command(name="hello", pass_context=True)(hellothere.callback)
```