# How to call async function for discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I have a (working) command that reads a file from my hard drive and plays it through my discord bot that reads:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def fp(ctx, file):
```

where file is the name of the item from a list. As some commands are used more often, I was wondering how I would go about referencing this function in another for the more common commands. Something along the lines of:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def crab(ctx):
    client.commands.fp(ctx, "crab")
```

but I can't get this working after much tinkering. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `Command.invoke` as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204867/how-to-give-a-command-multiple-names/50205556#50205556

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke) function like Patrick mentioned

```py
@bot.command()
async def crab(ctx):
    await fp.invoke(ctx, "crab")
```

or use a [`.callback`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command) function

```
@bot.command()
async def fp(ctx, file):
   // do something.

bot.command(name="crab")(fp.callback)
```