# discord.py: show messages counter in a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm a complete beginner in discord.py, I create a bot and try to count all messages posted in a channel. The bot will show this counter in a message when I call it with the command "!bot".

It works with the simple example "ping" (send "pong" successfully), but when I send "!bot" it returns an error in console:

```
[2022-09-09 16:59:37] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rinnosuke\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programmation\Python\Discord-bot\bot4.py", line 29, in on_message
    message_count()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

This is my code, what arguments should I pass to the message_count function call?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

prefix = "!b"
needed_intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=needed_intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.lower() == "ping":
        await message.channel.send('pong')
    if "!bot" in message.content:
        message_count()


@bot.command()
async def message_count(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    channel = bot.get_channel(586577242910359564)
    count = 0
    async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
        count += 1
    await message.channel.send("There were {} messages in {}".format(count, channel.mention))

client.run('my token')
bot.run('my token')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give a command multiple names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204867/how-to-give-a-command-multiple-names). I'm not sure why you're using multiple clients, but it seems like you're trying to add "!bot" as an alias for "!message_count"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include this `channel: discord.TextChannel=None` You can either set its type or set its value, not both.

Comment: I try to replace 'message_count' lines in 'on_message' function :

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.lower() == "ping":
        await message.channel.send('pong')
    if "!bot" in message.content:
        channel = bot.get_channel(586577242910359564)
 global count
 async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
  count += 1
 await message.channel.send("There were {} messages in {}".format(count, channel.mention))

Comment: But it sends this error message:

[2022-09-14 11:32:11] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rinnosuke\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programmation\Python\Discord-bot\bot4.py", line 35, in on_message
    async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history'